# Realization of Witten-type topological quantum field theory in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, topological-order, topological-field-theory

It is well-known that some exotic phases in condensed matter physics are described by [Schwarz-type TQFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory#Schwarz-type_TQFTs)s, such as Chern-Simons theory of quantum Hall states. My question is whether there are condensed matter systems that can realize [Witten-type TQFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory#Witten-type_TQFTs)s?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to only give one example of what a Witten-type TQFT is, and that is the WZW model which appears many places in condensed matter physics. I always thought that Witten type TQFT's are cohomological field theories, where there exist an operator $Q^2=0$ (so you have susy or BRST structure) and so on. I haven't seen any of these type theories in condensed matter physics

Comment: The type of TQFT's that Atiyah's axioms capture (where its a functor between certain appropriate categories) are the ones that usually appear in condensed matter context (at least in toy models). According to wikipedia, these include the Schwarz-type TQFT's but it is not clear that they describe the Witten-types fully.

Comment: @Heidar:  That wikipedia article is wrong.  The WZW model is not a topological field theory.  It's conformal, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @user1504 This is also the first time I have seen the WZW being called a topological field theory. The theory is gapless and has a lot of dynamical degrees of freedom, so its quite hard for me to see in what sense it could be topological.

Comment: It's simply not a topological field theory, and especially not one of Witten class.  Whoever edited that wikipedia article didn't know what they were talking about.  The WZW model isn't supersymmetric; it doesn't have a nilpotent supercharge.  (It's intimately related to Chern-Simons theory, but that's a different story, and not relevant here.)

Comment: It will be very helpful to explain what is  "Witten-type TQFTs"? At least to indicate if the theories have an energy gap, if the theories have supersymmetries, in which space-time dimensions, what are their Hamiltonian or Lagrangian, etc

Answer (score 6):

The TQFTs that Witten introduced are those obtained by a [topological twist](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological%20twist) of a supersymmetric field theory. This includes notably the [A-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A-model) and the [B-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/B-model) TQFTs.

Despite what seems to be suggested in the comments here and on Wikipedia, these are also "Schwarz type" (come from the [Poisson sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson%20sigma-model)) and they do have a desciption in terms of [functorial TQFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FQFT) if only one allows what are called [(infinity,1)-functors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity,1%29-functor): they are "[TCFTs](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/TCFT)" (i.e. non-compact 2d homotopy TQFTs).

Now, under [homological Mirror symmetry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mirror+symmetry) these are related to other TCFTs known as *[Landau-Ginzburg models](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Landau-Ginzburg%20model)*. And these do have applications in solid state physics.

Comment: I very much appreciate this answer because it actually defines what the question is asking about. But these Landau-Ginzburg models appear how in solid state? As fixed points of disordered systems in two dimensions?

Comment: Well, the Landau-Ginzburg theory is an old model for superconductivity and the behaviour of its potential term is what gives the Landau-Ginzburg model its name. But yeah, otherwise the relation is not super-close, I agree.

Comment: That's just a linguistic coincidence then... These models are by necessity supersymmetric and conformal (and even dimensional)? - the only place in solid state where I know of supersymmetric methods is in disordered systems/random matrices. If you don't know of a particular example, then that is fine, I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Are Witten-type theories unitary? Is there a reference to explain that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any Witten-type TQFTs which are directly relevant to condensed matter physics.   Witten-type TQFTs are very strange beasts: they violate spin-statistics, they aren't unitary, etc.  It'd be pretty tricky to find a physical system you could model with one in the usual way.

There are some indirect connections between Chern-Simons theory and Gromov-Witten theory, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: Why are Witten type TQFTs not unitary?

Comment: Why are Witten-type theories non-unitary? Can you please mention a reference?

Comment: The question about unitary is actual. Could you provide some reference?

Comment: Are Witten-type TQFTs really non-unitary?